# IOError on shutil.copy2

Tags: python

After running the below code,

```
import os, shutil, glob, sys
source_dir = sys.argv[1]

list = ['file1', 'fil2']
for seek in list:
        if seek == 'file1':
                dest_dir = '/root/my_dir'
        elif seek == 'file2':
                dest_dir = '/root/my_dir'
        paths = [(z, os.path.join(dest_dir, os.path.split(z)[1]))
                for z in glob.glob(os.path.join(source_dir, seek))]
        for p in paths:
                if os.path.isfile(p[1]):
                        new_path = p[1] + '.bak'
                        print ('File "{0}" already exists; 
                                moving to "{1}"'.format(p[1], new_path))
                        shutil.move(p[1], new_path)
                shutil.copy2(p[0], p[1])
```

following exception is generated:

```
File "./config1.py", line 22, in <module>
  shutil.copy2(p[0], p[1])
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.0/shutil.py", line 99, in copy2
  copyfile(src, dst)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.0/shutil.py", line 54, in copyfile
  copyfileobj(fsrc, fdst)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.0/shutil.py", line 30, in copyfileobj
  fdst.write(buf)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.0/io.py", line 1055, in write
  self._flush_unlocked()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.0/io.py", line 1082, in _flush_unlocked
    n = self.raw.write(self._write_buf)
IOError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
```

Comment: Silly question, but have you run out of disk space?

Comment: `No space left on device`?

Comment: @ Andreas, yes.. no space, that i know but it happened after executing this code,

Comment: I did not find why disk became full with this code..?

Comment: @Jaiswal You are copying (multiple) files, which uses additional disk space - it seems that there is not enough space available on the destination drive. How large are the files which are copied? How much disk space is left on the destination drive? Probably there are also no inodes left ... What is the output of `df -k /root/my_dir` and `df -i /root/my_dir`? Which file system are you using at all?

Comment: thanks, after freeing memory its working fine, but how to achieve the same operation for a directory .?

Answer (score 2):

Is your drive full ?

Also, those lines

```
    if seek == 'file1':
            dest_dir = '/root/my_dir'
    elif seek == 'file2':
            dest_dir = '/root/my_dir'
```

are useless, you're setting dest_dir to the same value in either case.

Just do

```
dest_dir = '/root/my_dir'
list = ['file1', 'fil2']
for seek in list:
    # your stuff
```

or, if you're planning to have other, different cases,

```
for seek in list:
    if seek in ('file1', 'fil2'):
        dest_dir = '/root/my_dir'
    elif seek in ('other_case', 'another_case'):
        dest_dir = '/foo'
```